# How to tune self join query in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g, self-join

Oracle & SQL new to me,and I'm still in learning phase.

Could you please help me to tune below oracle query??
This table contains ~95 lac records and it takes 1 hour to retrieve data using this query.

Your suggestions/comments/help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
    SELECT A.CNO   AS CNO,
       A.FNO AS FNO,
       A.CID AS CID,
       A.IID             AS IID
  FROM CAC_LKP A,
       (SELECT C_DATE, CNO, FNO
          FROM (SELECT MAX(CAC_LKP.C_DATE) AS C_DATE,
                       CAC_LKP.CNO AS CNO,
                       CAC_LKP.FNO AS FNO
                  FROM CAC_LKP
                 WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y'
                 GROUP BY CNO, FNO)) B
 WHERE A.C_DATE = B.C_DATE
   AND A.CNO = B.CNO
   AND A.FNO = B.FNO
   AND A.ACTIVE = 'Y'
```

Primary Key is defined over combination of c_date,iid,active.

Comment: What indexes you are having on your tables ?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the aggregation to get the most recent date for groups of variables.  You are then getting the rows that match those dates.

To optimize the query, forget the self-join and use analytic functions instead:

```
select cno, fno, cid, lid
from (select A.*,
             rank() over (partition by cno, fno order by c_date desc) as seqnum
      from cac_lkp A
      where A.active = 'Y'
     ) A
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Wow..great..It seems promising..will try this and let you know improvement in  performance..Thanks for quick help..:)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is huge data, the removal of unnecessary subquery can improve the performance. Make sure you are having indexes on the C_DATE, CNO, FNO and A.ACTIVE. Try this sql

```
SELECT A.CNO   AS CNO,
       A.FNO AS FNO,
       A.CID AS CID,
       A.IID             AS IID
  FROM CAC_LKP A,
       (SELECT MAX(CAC_LKP.C_DATE) AS C_DATE,
                       CAC_LKP.CNO AS CNO,
                       CAC_LKP.FNO AS FNO
                  FROM CAC_LKP
                 WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y'
                 GROUP BY CNO, FNO) B
 WHERE A.C_DATE = B.C_DATE
   AND A.CNO = B.CNO
   AND A.FNO = B.FNO
   AND A.ACTIVE = 'Y'
```

Comment: Thanks Ankur, I've tried with indexes but not seen such improvement.:(

Comment: @ParthSavjani : Please post your results after you try the query. Does above query or Gordon's query imporoved your response time ?